# Confusion Matrix produces different results in Keras model tf==2.3.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

With Keras Sequential Model Prediction,

To get Class Labels
we can do

```
yhat_classes1 = Keras_model.predict_classes(predictors)[:, 0] #this shows deprecated warning in tf==2.3.0

WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-54-226ad21ffae4>:1: Sequential.predict_classes (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential) is deprecated and will be removed after 2021-01-01.
Instructions for updating:
Please use instead:* `np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)`,   if your model does multi-class classification   (e.g. if it uses a `softmax` last-layer activation).* `(model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32")`,   if your model does binary classification   (e.g. if it uses a `sigmoid` last-layer activation).
```

so

```
yhat_classes2 = np.argmax(Keras_model.predict(predictors), axis=-1)
```

With the first class labels if i create confusion matrix, i get

```
matrix = confusion_matrix(actual_y, yhat_classes1)
 [[108579   8674]
 [  1205  24086]]
```

But with the second class labels with the confusion matrix, i get 0 for True Positive and False Positive

```
matrix = confusion_matrix(actual_y, yhat_classes2)
 [[117253      0]
 [ 25291      0]]
```

May I know whats my issue here?

Comment: how many neurons does your final layer have?

Comment: Keras_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=init_mode))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion matrix returns 2 rows/columns, which leads me to believe that you have two classes. The warning specifically says that you should use this line for **binary** classification, which is what you're doing:

```
(model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32")
```

> Please use instead:* `np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)`,   if your model does multi-class classification   (e.g. if it uses a `softmax` last-layer activation).* `(model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32")`,   if your model does binary classification   (e.g. if it uses a `sigmoid` last-layer activation).

The error is that you used `np.argmax(model.predict(X), axis=-1)` on a 1D output and so this always returns the same column (because there's only one, so the maximum value will be in that column). That explains that all your predicted values are in the same column in your confusion matrix.

Comment: yes, it is binary classification, only two classes, so returns the highest class

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you're trying to say

Comment: Just explained that you believe two classes

Comment: Tried this (model.predict(x) > 0.5).astype("int32"), this produces the correct result as yhat_classes1

Comment: The Warning message carried away